# warning warn(warning_msg) rpm

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-16.04, rpm

```
OS - Ubuntu-16.04 LTS
Python Version - 2.7.12
20.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

**Problem:**

```
python2 -c 'import rpm'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpm.py:15: UserWarning: The RPM Python bindings are not currently available via PyPI.

Please install them with your distro package manager (typically called
'python2-rpm' or 'python3-rpm'), and ensure that any virtual environments
needing the API are configured to be able to see the system site packages
directory.

  warnings.warn(warning_msg)
```

Due to above error my python script execution is failing. Please guide me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems quite clear to me. You need to use your distributions package manager to install rpm. Since you are using ubuntu and python 2, it should be

```
sudo apt-get install python-rpm
```

Comment: I have already installed apt-get install python-rpm but still not able to run my script.

Comment: Yes, I can see the output  # pip list | grep "rpm"
rpm                 0.0.2
rpm-py-installer    1.0.0
rpmfile             1.0.3

Comment: You will need to uninstall that version `pip uninstall rpm`

Comment: removed rpm, still same error.. pip list |grep rpm pyrpm               0.4
rpm-py-installer    1.0.0
rpmfile             1.0.3